# Parent/Child themes - both CSS files loaded

Tags: templates, child-theme, parent-theme

I am trying to use child themes for the first time in Wordpress - and I've got it working (at least from a user's perspective - it functions correctly)

My concern is that both the parent and child CSS files are loaded - so I'm concerned about performance. Ideally, I just want the child's CSS file used.

My code in functions.php is the following - does anyone have any suggestions how to just rely on the min.css file from the child template?

```
  <?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ); 
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'johannes-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/min.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'johannes-child-main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/min.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version')); 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want the paren't theme's stylesheet, just remove that line, and remove it as a dependency of the child theme, You can just enqueue the one stylesheet if you want.

Comment: I do that but the original stylesheet from the parent still shows?

Comment: Your parent theme is likely still enqueuing it (which is slightly odd because parent themes normally enqueue the child theme's stylesheet when one is active). You will need to use `wp_dequeue_style` to remove it, but you'll need to find the original handle inside the parent theme to know what to use.

Comment: Yep that solved the problem thanks! Just needed to dequeue the script